# Why does Jackson require ALWAYS visibility to detect multi-arguments setters?

Tags: java, jackson

With `JsonAutoDetect.Visibility` set to `ALWAYS`, a setter with multiple arguments is correctly invoked during deserialization.

```
public void setSize(
        @JsonProperty("width") Integer width, 
        @JsonProperty("height") Integer height) {
    super.setWidth(width);
    super.setHeight(height);
}
```

If I, on the other hand, try to limit the visibility of setters, with `setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE`, the setter is not used even though I explicitely flag it with `@JsonSetter`.

How can this behavior be explained? Why does [JACKSON-275](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-275) seem to imply that there is no support for multi argument setters while with a certain visibility level the support is already there?

Comment: I think this is a question for the dev forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jackson-dev

Comment: thanks - I just posted there too